# Should I take business trips when I know I'm quitting?

Tags: quitting

I got another offer and I'm about to leave my company in one month. The new contract has not been signed yet, so I haven't put in my 2-week notice. There is an extended business trip my team has been planning that takes place a week before my last day. The trip is essential to continue my current projects. Should I go on this trip even though I'm leaving? Or should I defer them until I put in my notice?

Comment: Potential duplicate - [Is it alright to quit right before a business trip?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33024/is-it-alright-to-quit-right-before-a-business-trip?rq=1)

Comment: Also useful - [What is expected of me during two weeks notice?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23298/what-is-expected-of-me-during-two-weeks-notice)

Comment: I think it depends on the kind of person you are. I'm loyal almost to a fault. I was in a similar situation, but used a planned ski trip as a reason for why I didn't attend a conference. I know that these things cost money and every dollar the company can save is useful to them.

Answer (score 9):

Until you put in your notice, you should continue to behave as if you will be remaining at your current company.  While the job appears to be in the bag, until you have a signed contract it could still fall though.

Comment: This, your superiors may fire you if you let them know that you are trying to get another job, and if the contract falls through then you have *no job!* I have personally have had promises that I would receive a contract fall through twice now, so it does happen.

Answer (score 2):

As others point out, you should do your job until you leave it. No notice given = haven't left it.

Although, if I worked for a small & underfunded organization, or close friends, I might bend that a little, and look for ways to reduce their expenses without tipping my hand. But if leaving a decent sized company where this travel expense isn't extreme, this is just a normal cost of business to them.

Comment: ... just be aware that this could backfire if the small organization turns around and fires you, or the close friend decides not to be a close friend anymore and fires you, and the new job falls through.

Comment: Definitely true... hence "without tipping hand." But yes, a delicate game.

Answer (score 1):

Get on your new employer's case to get the contract signed, put in your two-week's notice and see how events shape up. We have no idea how the management of your current employer is going to react and what decisions they'll make about you including your business trip.

Again,  the minute you've got your contract signed - the sooner, the better - give them your two-weeks' notice and let them sort out what to do about you including your business trip. It's less complicated to you that way. And it's the management's job anyway to work this sort of thing out.