# Fired from my job given two weeks notice but still expected to come to work not sure what is expected of me?

Tags: professionalism, communication, notice-period

Hello am 22 years old and have just been given two weeks notice (in lack of a better word fired) from my job as a manual QA but am still expected to come to work,
for these two weeks under the pretence that i can still learn a thing or two from my old place of employment.

My question is: what am i supposed to do for these two weeks i mean what is acceptable for a worker that has been given two weeks notice to do in that time before he/she is officially late go.

Note: am searching for a job and going to job interviews and my manager is fine with that, but accept that am not sure what to do in the office.

I don't want to take a days off because dose days off are worth quite a bit of money if you don't use them.

Comment: What did your manager ask you to do for these two weeks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is expected of me during two weeks notice?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23298/what-is-expected-of-me-during-two-weeks-notice)

Comment: I would be careful using the word "fired" - this word has a fairly specific meaning to hiring managers: typically, a "firing" is the same as "immediate dismissal" (generally, with cause such as negligence or incompetence). Since you have been given two weeks notice, I wouldn't characterise it as being fired - "let go" would probably be more accurate, and a lot less negative (with regards to your professional reputation) when talking about it to other people.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"what am i supposed to do for these two weeks?"

Your job. That's really all there is to it. Unless your manager has assigned you new tasks, you just come in and do your job. You are still employed by this company, you are still under the same contract, so you still do whatever you initially agreed to do for them.

Note that often you'll be asked to document what you do and/or help a new hire to perform your duties, but it seems you weren't asked this, so in that case just come in and do whatever it is that you normally do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. with all this process of geting fired and searching for a new job i wasn't thinking very clearly